# Unable to install self-signed SSL Cert. Apache Error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install a self signed cert I generated using these instructions here:

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

I have the cert ready and have reread the instructions several times. However, the one difference is that I'm putting mine in /etc/apache2/conf.d/security/

I get the following error from apache.

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/security/server.crt:
Invalid command '-----BEGIN', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Any clues? I'm in Ubuntu 11.04 running the latest lamp installation from tasksel. (vhosts in sites-available and such).  I also have also made sure that ssl is enabled using a2enmod ssl. It said that it was already enabled.

------------VHOST---------------

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.cmp.me

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/conf.d/security/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apach2/conf.d/security/server.key

        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/www.cmp.me
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/sites/www.cmp.me>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/errors/cmp-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please show your host configuration information.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, are you asking for apache2.conf, httpd.conf or the vhost file itself? The issue is occuring on startup for apache.

Comment: @arktype3 Whatever file you have used to define your vhost, which is where you define teh SSL cert configuration.  This is typically in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault.com.